# При импорте библиотеки Web3 получаю ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from')

Tags: javascript, blockchain, web3.py

Я не знаю как ее исправить, подскажите в чем может быть дело?
Я установил web3 - "web3": "^1.6.1"

**Вот сама ошибка:**

```
constants.ts:29 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'from')
    at node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/constants.js (constants.ts:29)
    at __require2 (chunk-324L4WHD.js?v=6750091b:48)
    at node_modules/ethereumjs-util/dist.browser/index.js (index.ts:4)
    at __require2 (chunk-324L4WHD.js?v=6750091b:48)
    at node_modules/web3-utils/lib/utils.js (utils.js:25)
    at __require2 (chunk-324L4WHD.js?v=6750091b:48)
    at node_modules/web3-utils/lib/index.js (index.js:24)
    at __require2 (chunk-324L4WHD.js?v=6750091b:48)
    at node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/formatters.js (formatters.js:24)
    at __require2 (chunk-324L4WHD.js?v=6750091b:48)
```

**Вот мой код:**

```
import Web3 from "web3";



export const Account = ({ id }) => {
  const balance = new web3.eth.Contract([], id, {
    from: "0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567891", // default from address
    gasPrice: "20000000000", // default gas price in wei, 20 gwei in this case
  });

  return <div>test</div>;
};
```

Comment: Попробуй подключить так `const Web3 = require("web3");`  в require свой путь до web3..

Comment: web3 - это же библиотека. Как я могу указать путь до нее ?

Comment: Если выполнял `npm install web3` в одной папке, а проект где используешь находится в другой, можешь прописать абсолютный путь до папки где лежит web3 `require("C:\Users\__NAME__\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\web3\web3.js")`

Comment: Я устанавливал его так как вы говорите, но самой папки node_modules\web3\web3.js у меня нету. Где  еще можно посмотреть ?

Comment: Команда  `npm install web3` подтягивает модули в текущую директорию должна появится папка `node_modules`, если проект в котором используется `web3` находится в той же директории `const Web3 = require("web3");` должно работать. Искать надо в директории где выполнялся `npm install web3`.